# jQuery Slider localScroll & Cycle function together - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently "trying" to implement both localscroll & cycle function together to create a slider. The slider is supposed to have two button (left and right) with an automatic cycle of rotation. The localscroll and the click function should have small buttons at the bottom where users can navigate to a certain image within the rotating slider.

The cycle function works. But the localscroll function is not working. [Please view the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xanxr/)

[Error image](http://i49.tinypic.com/66x7ur.jpg)

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $("#slideshow-nav").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#slideshow-nav a[href=#lambo1]").addClass("active");

    $("#slideshow-nav").localScroll({
            target:'#slideshow', axis: 'x'
    });

$("#slideshow-nav a").click(function(){
            $("#slideshow-nav a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $("ul#slides").cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            pause: 1,
            prev: '#prev',
            next: '#next'
    });

    $("#slideshow").hover(function() {
    $("ul#nav").fadeIn();
    },
            function() {
    $("ul#nav").fadeOut();
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Nivo Slider](http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/). Out of the box it has the features you're looking for, plus a lot of options, if you need to customize.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery("#nivoslider-4").nivoSlider({
    effect:"random",
    slices:15,
    boxCols:8,
    boxRows:4,
    animSpeed:500,
    pauseTime:3000,
    startSlide:0,
    directionNav:true,
    controlNav:true,
    controlNavThumbs:false,
    pauseOnHover:true,
    manualAdvance:false
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Currently i am working with a very closed system (CMS based). We are currently limited by the scripts we can use. This one seems safe and secure.